# Модуль auth, логинит только 1-ую запись в таблице

Tags: orm, php, auth, kohana

см. сразу **upd**

Kohana 3.2

Kohana уперто не хочет логинить пользователей. Исп. ORM драйвер. Логинит только 1-го пользователя в таблице, он же admin, который был там изначально. Пример кода:

```
public function action_index()
{

    $post = $this->request->post();

    if ($post) {    
        // если руками напишу как сейчас, то все срабатывает
        $success = Auth::instance()->login('admin','password');

    }

    if (isset($success) and $success) { echo "Пользователь залогинен"; }

}
```

Почему так может происходить? Может я как-то не так в Базу Данных пользователей вношу? Вношу только имя юзера username, email и пароль в захешированном виде. Ничего не упустил?

Программно заношу нового юзера в БД:

```
    $post = $this->request->post();
    $auth = Auth::instance();
    $user = new Model_User();
    $user->username = "Maris";
    $user->password = $auth->hash_password('psw123');
    $user->email = "me@email.com";
    $user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')));
    $user->save();
```

Результат:
`Database_Exception [ 1048 ]: Column 'user_id' cannot be null [ INSERT INTO`roles_users`(`user_id`,`role_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1') ]`

**Обновился** Так уже точно должно сработать:

```
public function action_index()
{

    $post = $this->request->post();
    $auth = Auth::instance();
    $user = new Model_User();
    $user->username = "Maris";
    $user->password = $auth->hash_password('psw123');
    $user->email = "me@email.com";
    $user->save();

    $user = ORM::factory('user')->where('username','=','Maris')->find();

    $user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')));

    if ($success = Auth::instance()->login('me@email.com','psw123'))
    {
        echo $user->name;
    }
}
```

Но увы, все без толку. В итоге юзер то добавляется в таблицу как положено и хеш пароля есть и роли, а логиниться не хочет?

**upd**
У меня опять проблемка. В общем логинится только юзер со привелегией `login`, остальное даже `instance` создавать не хочет, куда копать в таком случае?

Отвечу сам себе: должно быть две роли сразу.

Comment: Да... Что-то я уже совсем закодился, наверное надо сначала сохранить юзера в таблице users, а потом опять его брать из базы и присваивать роли. Это так... Мысли вслух, сейчас так и попробую.

Comment: Кажется я нашел в чем проблема, подводные камни, понимаешь ли... В общем хеши не совпадают того пароля который я в базу загоняю и того который просто-так ради интереса вывел, соответственно если их местами поменяю то все сработает.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, да, дей-но тут же при добавлении распределяется. Все равно как-то надо проверять who is who, т.е. кто админ, а кто простой юзер.

Comment: Ладно, оставим это, я уже при помощи чуть-ли ни через Query Builder решил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо добавить пользователю роль `login`, иначе он залогиниться [не сможет](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/auth/orm.php#L85). Программно делается так:

```
$user = ...; // пользователь
$user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')));
```

Вот этого делать не надо:

```
$user->password = $auth->hash_password('psw123');
```

Kohana [сама выполнит](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.2/master/classes/model/auth/user.php#L55) хеширование. Пишите:

```
$user->password = 'psw123';
```

Comment: См. я обновил вопрос. Чем ему user_id yt угодило не пойму?

Comment: @Maris, я обновил ответ

Comment: А ок! Сейчас попробую тогда, так и думал что в хешах собака зарыта.

Comment: Да! Решилось! Вот видишь, не знал таких нюансов, не в каждом туториале есть, спасибо что помог!

Comment: Туториалы устаревают - вся правда в исходниках, а у Kohana они довольно легко читаются.

Comment: А как узнать привелегию залогиненного пользователя?

Comment: Привилегию? Ту, которая роль? Если так, то вы бы открыли первую ссылку, которая объясняет почему без роли ``login`` нельзя войти, и увидели бы вот это:

    if ($user->has('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')) ...